# How do I completely get rid of the dock from GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

I have tried using

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

but the dock is still present when I open the Activities overview and show all programs. How do I completely get rid of it?